# Put several objects into ArrayList in one line

Tags: java, arraylist

I have several Objects from Type `org.eclipse.swt.widget.Control` and I want to put them in an `ArrayList` in just one line.

```
List<Control> list = new ArrayList<Control>();
Label label = new Label(container, SWT.None);
label.setText("Label");
combo = createCCombo(container, Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
combo.select(0);
list.add(label);
list.add(combo);
```

I want to replace the two lines at the and with just one. How can Ido this with highest performance and does it makes sence if I just have two `Control` objects, which I want to put in the list?

Comment: If `label` and `combo` are related you may want a class to handle them together (`new LabelCombo(label, combo)`), or a mapping from `label` to `combo` (`Map<Label, Combo>`).

Comment: I guess `list.add(label); list.add(combo);` doesn't satisfy your needs?

Comment: Adding two widgets to an `ArrayList` is your performance bottleneck?  I _really_ doubt that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(label, combo));
```

Answer (score 1):

i consider the answer by @kocko the most simple and a correct solution to the question asked here.

Though if you do it in a loop, this solution could eventually be more efficient, as it prevents creating new temporary `List`s:

```
final List<Control> list = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Control> labelCombo = new ArrayList<>(2);
for (...) {
    labelCombo.set(0, label);
    labelCombo.set(1, combo);
    list.addAll(labelCombo);
}
```

**But** for potential followers (and the OP himself), a word of **warning**:

Performance optimization should be done with actually testing the performance, and finding out with measurements (profiler) where you loose performance, and testing your pre and post "fix" solutions against each other.

In the case at hand, it is virtually impossible that this method will give you performance, and very likely that it will give you worse performance.
This is due to the way `ArrayList` is expanding its storage size behind the scenes. if you manage to trigger this less often, and in turn save more performance then the overhead of setting/adding each `Control` 2 times (first to `labelCombo`, then to `list`), then you would save performance. I challenge you to find a practical example to do that though.